# Trouble Binding CollectionViewSource to ListBox

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I have a main window that contains a ContentControl. The ContentControl has a couple of DataTemplates that are loaded based on binding conditions, the Templates contain a UserControl which houses a styled ListBox called ThumbListBox.

I'm trying to bind a CollectionViewSource to the ListBox in XAML but can't seem to get it to work.

I have the CollectionViewSource (called ThumbnailDataView) defined in a ResourceDictionary called DataSources.xaml. I have added DataSources.xaml to my Merged Dictionaries in my main window

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Templates/DataSources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>  
</Window.Resources>
```

As well as added the DataSources.xaml to the merged dictionaries in the UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Templates/DataSources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I am creating a reference to the CollectionViewSource in my code behind:

```
Public ThumbnailDataView As CollectionViewSource    
AppLocal.ThumbnailDataView = CType(Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources("ThumbnailDataView"), CollectionViewSource)
```

I need the ListBox to be bound to the ThumbnailDataView CollectionViewSource and then I need to be able to set the CollectionViewSource source in code-behind because I need to set different Lists (Of ObservableCollection) at various points in the applications lifetime (e.g. based on triggers).

This here is my ListBox.

For some reason, the ListBox is not receiving any data.

I can't bind the CollectionViewSource to the parent DataTemplate or UseControl because I already have another List bound at that level already.

Can I create a CollectionViewSource in a ResourceDictionary and then reference the ResourceDictionary from my main window to allow StaticResource access to the CollectionViewSource?